# Is there a single word for "tomorrow night?"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word to express the concept of nighttime tomorrow like how we already have "today," "tonight," "tomorrow," and "overmorrow."

Comment: Have you tried any synonym searches?

Comment: I did, but nothing turned up. It could very well be that no such word exists, but I will be disappointed should that be the case.

Comment: I have never heard anyone say _overmorrow_. Would it be possible to stick to two words?

Comment: I've never heard the concept described as anything but 'tomorrow night'. 'Overmorrow' seems to exist but is an extremely obscure word.

Comment: @JohnFeltz: Do you have any reason to think that a "synonym search" (whatever that is) would work here? There clearly is no such word...

Answer (score 3):

There is no commonly used word to describe *tomorrow night*. There could be an archaic word for it, such as how *yestereve* refers to *yesterday night*, but it would be too obscure to use in conversation.